# Pushing GitHub to GitLab

Tags: github, gitlab

For a class I've been putting all my work in a GitHub repository but it needs to be in GitLab. I logged into GitLab through GitHub and everything carried over properly. The problem is, whenever I push to GitHub, the changes don't go through to GitLab. I tried making a codespace in GitHub that pushes the changes to GitLab but it still doesn't work. Is there anything I can do to make it automatically push to GitLab when I push to GitHub?

Here's the code I used in the codespace that I got off a GitHub community post

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel 
git remote add gitlab <Repository URL>
git config --global credential.helper store
git push gitlab
Username: <username> 
Password: <Access token>
git push gitlab <Repository name>
```

Comment: Edit your `.git/config` and rename the `gitlab` section to `origin` and choose another name for the original `origin`. A normal `git push` will go to `origin`.

Answer (score 0):

I could tell you how to do this on the command line, since Git is able to work with multiple remotes just fine.

But there's a simpler way in your case:

1. Go to Gitlab and click <kbd>New project</kbd>

[image: Gitlab New project button]

2. Click **Import project**.

[image: Gitlab Import project]

3. Click Repository by URL and enter the public URL for the GitHub project (the HTTPS one).

(*I know the GitHub button is tempting, but it uses Oauth and I just don't want to expend the effort to set that up.*)

[image: Gitlab import Repository by URL]

4. Click <kbd>Create project</kbd> at the bottom of the page

Comment: This still isn't working for me, even when I enable mirroring. GitLab does not update to the current GitHub branch after importing. I should also preface that I am using only GitHub and not Git so that's probably the problem.